# How to access matching object property in another JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have 2 objects, one of which starts as a copy of the other. I would like to be able to check if a different values have changed i.e. that they no longer match:

```
var obj = {
    key1: {
        innerKey: "val"
    },
    key2: "matching val"
};

var copy = {
    key1: {
        innerKey: "non-matching val"
    },
    key2: "matching val"
};
```

I would like to have some sort of `hasChanged()` method which would work something as follows:

```
hasChanged(obj.key1.innerKey); // result true
hasChanged(obj.key2); // result false
```

It seems I need some way to get the "path" or location of the property in order to find that property on the other object for comparison, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to pass three args:  `hasChanged(obj1, obj2, "key1.innerKey")`.  Then, you can look for that property on both objects by parsing it into it's pieces and looking it up on both objects.

Comment: You may be interested in Object.observe https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: @joe Please try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [lodash library](http://lodash.com) has just what I'm looking for here:

```
_.get(obj, path);
```

e.g.
    _.get(obj, 'key1.innerKey'); // "val"

so:

```
function hasChanged(obj, backup, path) {
    var objVal = _.get(obj, path);
    var backupVal = _.get(backup, path);
    return objVal !== backupVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $.fn.hasChanged = function(obj,key){
   var origObj = this[0];
   
   var originalValue = Object.byString(origObj,key);
    var currentValue = Object.byString(obj,key);
   return !(originalValue == currentValue);
  
};
     
Object.byString = function(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
}



var obj = {
    key1: {
        innerKey: "val"
    },
    key2: "matching val"
};

var copy = {
    key1: {
        innerKey: "non matching val"
    },
    key2: "matching val"
};
alert($(obj).hasChanged(copy,'key1.innerKey'));
alert($(obj).hasChanged(copy,'key2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bipashant. v. interesting.